# Can not render stage - javascript and pixijs

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games, pixi.js

I am very new in making game and pixijs, I am having a trouble in render stage. 
This is my code, I have draw function to render in baseScreen, and I use it by code

```
this.screens[i].draw();
```

in screenManage, and I don't know why I can not render the stage on canvas. 
There are no error notice but I do not see the loadBackground file. 
Thank you so much for all the help.

game.js

```
import ScreenManager from '../framework/screens/screenManager.js';

export default class Game
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.frames = 0;
  }

  init()
  {
    this.screenManager = new ScreenManager(this);
    this.screenManager.loadContent();

    this.screenManager.draw();
  }
}
```

screenManager.js

```
import LoadingScreen from './loadingScreen.js';

export default class ScreenManager
{
  constructor(game)
  {
    this.game = game;
    this.screens = new Array();
    this.canvas = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(1024, 768);
    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas.view);
  }

  loadContent()
  {
    this.loadingScreen = new LoadingScreen('loadingScreen');
    this.loadingScreen.loadContent();
    this.addScreen(this.loadingScreen);
  }

  addScreen(screen)
  {
    this.screens.push(screen);
  }

  draw()
  {
    for(var i=0;i<this.screens.length;i++)
    {
      console.log(this.screens[i]);
      this.screens[i].draw();
    }
  }
```

baseScreen.js

```
export default class BaseScreen
{
  constructor(name, screenManager)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.sm = screenManager;
    this.stage = new PIXI.Container();
  }

  // Render
  draw()
  {
    this.sm.canvas.render(this.stage);
  }
}
```

loadingScreen.js

```
import BaseScreen from './baseScreen.js';

export default class LoadingScreen extends BaseScreen
{
  constructor(name, screenManager)
  {
    super(name, screenManager);
  }

  loadContent()
  {
    this.loadBackground = PIXI.Sprite.from('assets/images/Preloader.png');
    this.stage.addChild(this.loadBackground);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is strange that you dont get any error because LoadingScreen class constructor needs 2 arguments, but you pass only one: `new LoadingScreen('loadingScreen')` - so you dont pass `screenManager`. This should cause error on this call: `this.sm.canvas....` . Also please try to make sure that `BaseScreen.draw()` function is really called (for example: add some console.log there etc).

Comment: Other problem that i see is the multiple renders per frame - the `this.screens[i].draw();` call in loop. You should have only 1 "render" call per frame - because "render" overrides what was displayed by previous render. You should try to setup proper main loop, with 1 render per frame - so 1 "stage" container, but inside this "stage" you can put multiple other containers (for example: your BaseScreen's etc). Please see for example following articles: https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/37359-when-do-i-need-to-call-rendererrenderstage/ , http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=5226

Comment: and demos in: https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-basic/container.js - they show simplified "main game loop" using pixi "ticker".